# Beamer: include name and date in the title's block

Tags: beamer

I am rather new to Beamer and currently preparing a presentation where my title slide features a background image. It looks like this :

[image: My beamer slide]

I want to include the name and the date in the blue block (and make them white as well). How can I manage to do it ?

EDIT. My code is the following :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\title{La Banque Centrale Européenne et ses actions}
\author{My name”}
\date{Janvier 2023}

\begin{document}

{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth].{eurosymbol.jpeg}}
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Many thanks for flagging this, I added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redefine the `title page` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\title{La Banque Centrale Européenne et ses actions}
\author{My name}
\date{Janvier 2023}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
      \vskip1em\par
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
      \vskip1em\par
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}}
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked !

Comment: European Central Bank secretly run by ducks? No wonder we kept the pound...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes :) The yellow stars you see in the question? That's just the crown of the duck seen from above :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's also why it is located in Frankfurt am Main, next to a big river